# What are the currently supported Python versions?

Tags: python

Python 2.7 reached end of life with the end of 2019 ([PEP 373](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#id2)). But which are the currently supported Python versions?

I realize that "supported" might mean many things (e.g. AWS Lambda currently supports Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8). To make this question objective, let's say: which CPython versions still receive security updates and for how long?

Comment: I've summarized my thoughts on this topic here: [Current Python Versions](https://martin-thoma.com/current-python-versions/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Status of current python branches](https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches)

[Python 3.6 Lifespan](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0494/#lifespan)

> 3.6 will receive bugfix updates approximately every 3 months for about 24 months. Sometime after the release of 3.7.0 final, a final 3.6 bugfix update will be released. After that, it is expected that security updates (source only) will be released as needed until 5 years after the release of 3.6 final, so until approximately 2021-12.

[Python 3.7 Lifespan](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0537/#id10)

> 3.7 will receive bugfix updates approximately every 3 months for about 24 months. Sometime after the release of 3.8.0 final, a final 3.7 bugfix update will be released. After that, it is expected that security updates (source only) will be released as needed until 5 years after the release of 3.7 final, so until approximately 2023-06.

[Python 3.8 Lifespan](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0569/#lifespan)

> 3.8 will receive bugfix updates approximately every 1-3 months for approximately 18 months. After the release of 3.9.0 final, a final 3.8 bugfix update will be released. After that, it is expected that security updates (source only) will be released until 5 years after the release of 3.8 final, so until approximately October 2024.

[Python 3.9 Lifespan](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0596/#lifespan)

> 3.9 will receive bugfix updates approximately every month for approximately 12 months. After the release of 3.10.0 final, a final 3.9 bugfix update will be released. After that, it is expected that security updates (source only) will be released until 5 years after the release of 3.9 final, so until approximately October 2025.

Comment: Interesting - so it's unclear if Python 3.5 still is alive? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0478/

Comment: Python 3.5 is still alive. End of life is apprximately on 2020-09-13.
https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches